# Save Username into session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to select the logged in user out from the database and show it on the display. The problem is I tried to save the Username into a session, but as I am not so known with php, it doesn't work.

If you guys would please give me some hints or could tell me what I do wrong I would be thankful.

```
include('navbar.php'); // Session start is called here

require_once "DB.inc.php";

require_once('navbar.php');

$link = mysql_connect($DB_server, $DB_user, $DB_password,$DB_name);  
     //   mysql_select_db('linux', $link) or die(mysql_error()); 

    $username = $_SESSION["username"];

    require_once "DB.inc.php";

    $db = mysqli_connect($DB_server, $DB_user, $DB_password, $DB_name);

    $befehl = $db->query("SELECT U_Username FROM u_user WHERE U_Username='$username'"); 

    $resultat = $befehl->fetch_object();

    mysqli_close($db);

echo $resultat->U_Username
```

Comment: You need to start the session before saving anything in the `$_SESSION` array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: First you need to start the session with `session_start();`. Then you have two connections `$link = mysql_connect($DB_server, $DB_user, $DB_password,$DB_name);` which this one should be deleted. Plus repeated calls to required files. Then you're closing your connection before you can use `echo $resultat->U_Username` which is missing a semi-colon.

Comment: the session is started in navbar.php, that's why i include it up in the code!

Comment: Closers and voters, this is a valid question. OP has provided his code and is not asking for a library or a recommendation. Please don't vote to close unless you have a real reason. If you find a duplicate, feel free to vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: anyway thank you for the answer but it won't help me fixing the problem

Comment: @linuxprofessor Please [edit] to include exactly what kind of behavior you expect, and what you get instead. Are you getting an error? An empty string?

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION["username"]`?

Comment: Where are you saving the username in the session?. i.e. where do you populate that session variable?

Comment: It's going to be really hard to give a definite solution for this, seeing the OP doesn't have much experience in PHP (*"but as I am not so known with php"*), therefore falls under the "show me how to code in PHP" type of question. @SecondRikudo Not to mention MySQL and the many errors in the OP's code. I've already outlined a few errors already in a comment above. I voted to close as "why is it not working". OP needs to read proper tutorials.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: username  on line 70

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  on line 81

Comment: <?php
session_start();


require_once "redirect.inc.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION[''username']))
{
redirect('Login.php');
die();
$q =mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM u_users WHERE U_Benutzername ='.$_SESSION[lusername].'"); 
}
//setcookie("sessionid",$_SESSION["id"],time()+(3600*24*100));

?>

Comment: As per my original comment; you need to get rid of any code containing `mysql_` because `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions do not intermix with each other. You will need to read tutorials on this. It is going to be far too difficult to give you a definite answer/solution. Here is one http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should and http://codular.com/php-mysqli and the manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php then for sessions http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php - Good luck.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem. thank you for everyone who helped me :)